# AS3: Quick question regarding children and referencing them

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, children

**Edit:** Cameron requested the full offending function:

```
function picSwitch(p=null)
{
 if (picShown == true)
 {
  picx = 3072;
  picy = 2304;
  picTweens.removeChild(pic);
  picShown = false;
 }
 else
 {
  var pic:image = new image();
  pic.smoothing = true;

  pic.width = 750;
  pic.height = 560;

  if (pic.scaleX < pic.scaleY) 
  {
   pic.scaleY = pic.scaleX;
  } 
  else 
  {
   pic.scaleX = pic.scaleY;
  }

  picx = 1536 - (pic.width/2) + 64;
  picy = 1152 - (pic.height/2) - 12;

  picTweens.addChild(pic);

  TweenLite.to(pic, 1, {x:picx, y:picy, rotation:4, ease:Quint.easeInOut});

  picShown = true;
 }
}
```

**Original Post:**
Oh man, I can't believe I've spent several hours on this one.. such a stupid question that undoubtedly has been asked many times before.. I apologise to you all in advance..

I'm having problems referencing a child I created.

I've got a movie clip in my library called 'image'

a container movie clip called 'picTweens' on my stage (its instance name is the same)

and in the actions panel in the stage i've got a function which contains

```
var pic:image = new image();
pic.smoothing = true;
picTweens.addChild(pic);
```

all well and good, it creates me a movie clip where it's supposed to.

now in an if statement in the same function, i have

```
picTweens.removeChild(pic);
```

but when that if statement triggers, (and i've got my pic loaded where it's supposed to be)

it tells me :

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
```

is my syntax wrong? and if not, then what should i check for?

Comment: Can you post the offending function in its entirety?

Comment: Edited with full offending function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So obvious. The *pic* variable simply is NOT available when you want to remove the child. You declared it in the "else" part, and it was in some function (which I would guess is called on a button press, or enter frame, or any other event). Therefore, when the function is called AGAIN, this time with *picShown* set to true, the *pic* variable is NOT available, and it is null.

Either that OR you did actually declare the variable OUTSIDE of the function, but with "var" inside the functions scope, it was overwritten locally.

So - make sure to declare the *pic* variable outside the function, so you will be able to access the handle later:

```
var pic:image;
function picSwitch(...){
    // etc.
}
```

Also - when you have that, do NOT redeclare the *pic* variable INSIDE the function, use just a simple assignment ( pic = blah; ).

Comment: Augh! >___< I knew it was something stupid like that. Terribly sorry for this waste of space.

Indeed it was the scope of my var pic:image = new image();

*facepalm*